# C# Pointing to a List<T> (WinForms)

Tags: c#, list, pointers

I've been wondering for a while now about how to correctly do this but I'm not entirely sure.

I want to create a List of usernames and use a foreach loop to draw the usernames to the screen. The List of usernames is a static list that will be held in the MainClass and the drawing process will happen in another class (For this instance we will call it the Printer class).

My 'issue' is that I want to make it so that I'm not just copying that List from the MainClass into a seperate List into the Printer class so when I add/remove an object from the list, the Printer class can instantly tell that it has changed.

*Edit: I don't so much need to worry about the event of the list changing as the list will be printed on a Paint event. I mainly need to create a new variable in the Printer class and "link" that variable with the List in question when the class is first initialized*

I cannot just simply use MainClass.usernameList inside of Printer because it will be used for multiple Lists at once and copying the MainClass list will just provide me with a list that never updates (Unless I tell it to however this can get tedious with many simultaneous classes).

I assume I need to use Pointers however I've never used them before and the whole Unsafe code idea seems... Unsafe.

**Summary:**
I need to create a variable in a public class that points to a static List in another class.

The code is pretty scruffy but hopefully people get a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You want to do this by [binding to an `ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, don't use WinForms for new projects unless you have to for some known reason. WPF is the more modern framework and e.g. data binding was part of the design since day one, instead of being an afterthought.

Comment: I would go about your problem a bit differently, define a new class `MyList` and add events that would be triggered when a new item is added to the list using a function `Additem` this way you would know when something is added/changed in your list

Comment: You don't need unsafe code or pointers for this, you just need to share the reference to the `ObservableCollection` (or some other data source) between your GUI objects. Remember that in C# passing an object (that's not a value type) around does **not** copy it.

Comment: @JafarKofahi That's kind of what `ObservableCollection` already does. No point reimplementing it

Comment: @millimoose thanks for pointing that out I didnt know about ObservableCollection until you guys mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not seeing anyone answer with an approach that would let you listen to something happening in your **`List<T>`**.

To do that, you would create a basic little wrapper for your list that would include at least one EventHandler object that you would need to wire up.

Here is a very basic implementation that I just threw together:

```
public class SubscribeList<T> : IList<T> {

  private List<T> list;

  public EventHandler OnListContentsChange;

  public SubscribeList() {
    list = new List<T>();
  }

  public int IndexOf(T item) {
    return list.IndexOf(item);
  }

  public void Insert(int index, T item) {
    list.Insert(index, item);
    OnListContentsChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  public void RemoveAt(int index) {
    list.RemoveAt(index);
    OnListContentsChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  public T this[int index] {
    get {
      throw new NotImplementedException(); // do this if you want,
    }
    set {
      throw new NotImplementedException(); // but it is more complicated
    }
  }

  public void Add(T item) {
    list.Add(item);
    OnListContentsChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  public void Clear() {
    list.Clear();
    OnListContentsChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  public bool Contains(T item) {
    return list.Contains(item);
  }

  public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) {
    list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    OnListContentsChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }

  public int Count {
    get { return list.Count; }
  }

  public bool IsReadOnly {
    get { return false; }
  }

  public bool Remove(T item) {
    var ok = list.Remove(item);
    if (ok) {
      OnListContentsChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    return ok;
  }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    foreach (var item in list) yield return item;
  }

  System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return list.GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Now, you are saying this:

> **Summary:** I need to create a variable in a public class that points to a static List in another class.

OK, let's start with a static List in another class. Don't laugh:

```
public class AnotherClass {

  public static SubscribeList<String> List;

  static AnotherClass() {
    List = new SubscribeList<string>();
    List.OnListContentsChange += new EventHandler(List_ContentsChanged);
  }

  private static void List_ContentsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("The contents of the list have changed! Call your Redraw Code.");
  }

}
```

That `OnListContentsChanged` EventHandler has to be wired up so that your code knows how to react when the list changes.

Now, to create the variable in a public class that points to this list, you could do something like the following:

```
public class PublicClass {

  private SubscribeList<String> list;

  public PublicClass() {
    list = AnotherClass.List;
  }

  private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    list.Add("Someone or txtName.Text from your form"); // this will fire the AnotherClass.List_ContentsChanged EventHandler.
  }

}
```

Notice I have created a fictitious button click event that adds an item to your static list.

Also, notice if your **List** in `AnotherClass` is never created, you are going to get an exception thrown here.

If that is not what you are after, then I simply did not understand your question.

Comment: Is there a reason you implemented what is already in `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Comment: **ObservableCollection<T>** is `WPF`, and the OP specifically stated `WinForms`. He may not have access to the WPF library/framework. Besides, there were lots of other comments already telling him about the **ObservableCollection<T>**, and he hadn't accepted those. The **ObservableCollection** can not always be dropped into a big project that is already using an old fashioned **List<T>** without making coding modifications.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` is **NOT** WPF, it is in the `System.dll.`

Comment: This answer is a waste of time. Use ObservableCollection<T>. Anyone would do that

Comment: @j2pcode If `ObservableCollection` cannot always be dropped into a big project that is already using an old fashioned `List<T>` without making coding modifications, nor can the solution you've provided. -1 from me.

Comment: `ObservableCollection` requires .Net 3.0 or above.

Comment: The rest of you need to learn how to read what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @JoeStead: My class exposes the same methods as the implemented class **List<T>**. So it is possible that the OP (or anyone else) could simply change the definition and declaration.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` already implements `IList<T>`, it's at best trivial to change any methods that expect a `List` to `IList`. And since the whole point of the exercise (i.e. "what the OP is asking for") is subscribing to the change notification events that `ObservableCollection` has and `List` does not, how easy it is to "drop in" isn't really that important if you'll have to make more complex code changes elsewhere to actually benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem should not be solved the way you are doing; anyway if you use a **ObservableCollection** you can be notified when an element is added and removed from the list and then you can react.

Moreover if your list is static you don't need to pass references around, but if you do, you are still referencing to the same object so you always have the updated list around.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your list an `ObservableCollection<T>` and then implement logic in other classes that bind to your collection's `CollectionChanged` event.

So you simply store your collection wherever that is useful, and then implement event handlers for the `CollectionChanged` event in helper classes or controls or wherever you need them. The event handlers will get called whenever the contents of the collection change:

```
myCollection.CollectionChanged += SomeHelperClass.OnCollectionChanged;
```

and in your helper class you write

```
public void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // process e.NewItems
    ...

    // process e.OldItems
    ...
}
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: worthwhile to remember that adding the event handler to a static list from the Printer class will result in memory/reference leak. So the event handler must be removed when the printer form is unloaded.

Comment: @RononDex: This answer fulfills OP's requirements, whereas yours does not... It is necessary to respond to changes in the list, as OP points out.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need unsafe block for this. All objects are by default references, the contents are not copied.

```
var x = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

var printer = new Printer();

// this assignment does not copy the list - it assigns the property to the same list
printer.UserList = x;

// verify that the reference was copied, not the data
x.Add(4);
printer.UserList.Add(5);

MessageBox.Show(x.Count.ToString()); // shows 5
MessageBox.Show(printer.UserList.Count.ToString()); // also shows 5
```

This is the main difference between `class` and `struct`. If you would have a `struct` then it would be instead copied with all its integer, `DateTime` etc. variables.